# awk syntax — what is OFS and why the 1 at the end?

Tags: shell, awk

```
awk -F"\t" -v OFS="\t" '{if($18~/^ *[0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?" *$/)sub(/"/,"",$18);else $18=" "}1' sample.txt
```

The code above is some `awk` code used in a script I'm modifying. I'm new to Unix so am not able understand the syntax of the above `awk`.

- `-F` is for splitting the colum with the delimeter.
- What is `OFS`?
- And what is the use of 1 at the end of the `awk` script?

Comment: OFS is the output field separator, used to separate `$1` from `$2` when you run `print`.  And the 1 is always true, and so it triggers the default action, which is `print` (aka `print $0`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-v OFS="\n"` passes a param named `OFS` from the shell to the awk script. Like the -F option or `FS` it is the field separator - but for the output. It is called the *output field separator*

You can test it:

```
awk -v OFS=' ' '{print 1,2}' a.txt
```

Output separated by spaces:

```
1 2
1 2
```

.

```
awk -v OFS=';' '{print 1,2}' a.txt
```

Output separated by `;`:

```
1;2
1;2
```

In your case it means, that the output will be separated by tabs (as the input)

---

The `1` at the end of the awk script, let awk print the original input line in addition to the script generated output. That's because an awk script usually contains tests (regex, etc) and actions for them. The test `1` will be always true. And as the default action of `awk` is printing the current line, it will print the line